# It is possible to integrate cypress with google sheets?

Tags: automation, cypress

I just want to automate my monitoring in optimizing my website and i know how to visit, get elements and get strings and values in cypress but i want it to automate and write down the strings and value on google sheets.

I've been searching in google but no luck.

It is possible to do this way on cypress? or if you have recommendations and documentations that would be a great help

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install googleapis
```

Just make sure to call google apis via tasks, not commands neither via tests. Because those run on browser and will require tons of polyfills to make it work.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) is some example and pre-configuration steps.